# Substract one year to a Pandas Period Serie

Tags: python, pandas, date, series

I have a pandas series which is a `Period` object with frequency `W-SUN`

```
>>dft_history.date
dtype: period[W-SUN]
```

I wanna keep this frequency, but being able to filter values one year in the past from now on. To do so, I rest to this periods 1 year, but I get an error:

```
>>dft_history.date - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
IncompatibleFrequency: Input has different freq=<-1 * DateOffset: years=1> from PeriodArray(freq=W-SUN)
```

So I have tried to set other time frequencies to `pd.DateOffset` but still I could not achieve the result. Is there a way to do this keeping the W-SUN frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't subtract the `Dateoffset` from the `Period` also to compare two different periods they must have the same frequency. One way to approach this problem is to first make sure the frequency of the periods is same

```
lower = pd.Timestamp('now') - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
dft_history[dft_history['date'] >= lower.to_period('W-SUN')]
```